# How can i write limits on top of summation?

Tags: equations

can someone tell me How can i write the limits on top of summation. My code is:

```
$\pdv{T^k}{t}$ = $-(\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{cat}C_t^k})(\frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z})+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{cat}C_t^kC_p^k}+\frac{\rho_{cat}a}{\varepsilon_{cat}C_t^kC_p^k}$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{f,i}^k)$\\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you typeset this formula in display-math mode. As a nice side-effect of making this switch, the limits of summation will be placed above and below the `\sum` symbol automatically. Moreover, the `\frac` terms will also be enlarged -- probably much to the delight (relief?) of your readers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\pdv[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} % ?
\begin{document}
\noindent
Original form, with some code cleaning applied:

$\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k)$

\bigskip
\noindent
Same formula, but in displaymath mode:
\[
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k)
\]
\end{document}
```